# Not expected result from mathematical operation

Tags: php

Why this code returns `false`, can you explain me why this happened?

```
var_dump( 85.4 + 42.7 == 128.1  );  // bool(false)
```

Comment: I suspect that `85.4 + 42.7` evaluates to `128.099999999999` or something like that.

Comment: Please read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: never equate floats like that. welcome to computer world!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yet again, [floating point](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) precision.  You can't rely on precise comparison when dealing with floats. Instead, you should use precision delta:

```
$a = 85.4+42.7;
$b = 128.1;
$delta = 1E-13;

if(abs($a-$b)<$delta)
{
   //they are equal
}
```

-here `$delta` is precision delta. For PHP, `1E-13` would be quite enough. The manual says:

> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on
>   the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format,
>   which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order
>   of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger
>   errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when
>   several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
>   floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
>   exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
>   used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
>   cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
>   small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for
>   example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
>   expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
>   7.9999999999999991118....
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
>   compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher
>   precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp
>   functions are available.
>
> For a "simple" explanation, see the » floating point guide that's also
>   titled "Why don’t my numbers add up?"

Comment: nice one, wanted to write same answer, but you were faster :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of floating point numbers imperfect precision, read about it more here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php